# Developing Ruby on an Android tablet

Tags: android, ruby

I want to do Ruby development on an Android tablet, just like on any laptop. So, using vim, git, and rspec to run tests. So, I've found the following apps:

- Vimtouch
- Ruboto
- Git (yes, it's an app)
- Terminal Emulator (provides bash)

Each app works just fine. By itself. But, I don't know how to put it all together. I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to how Android works. So, if anyone could help provide a writeup so that I can:

- clone a github repository
- edit files from that repository
- run my tests

**NOTE**: I don't want to write an Android app. I want to use my tablet to do Ruby development.

Comment: you want to install Ruby and Ruby on Rails on an Android?

Comment: Not rails. Just ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Scripting Environment [said to plan on Ruby](http://google-opensource.blogspot.de/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html). Might be worth a check how far they got; at least they're tagged "JRuby" at Google Code. According to [their project page:](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)

---

Scripts can be run interactively in a terminal, in the background, or via Locale. Python, Perl, JRuby, Lua, BeanShell, JavaScript, Tcl, and shell are currently supported, and we're planning to add more.

---

this can be done

1. Compile Ruby and Nodejs for android
2. Install on device and configure with c/c++ ide (You can use
   C4droid,CCTools,Terminal IDE.... for installing the expansion
   modules on с/с++)

Comment: This doesn't help me to edit files in vimtouch to use in SL4A.